# SQL Select inner join from (Select inner join)?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Hi I try to select data inner join from inner join from another table (It weird when I say it without example,that why I didn't get any result from Google).
this is my Database.

[My Database flowchart Picture](http://image.ohozaa.com/view2/xqG7d6ROKsEGTp1t)

I want to select **Product_Total.Product_Name** from Product_Total instant of Product_Id in table Product_Customer

```
| Barcode_Id  | Product_Name  | Sub_Id  | Department_Name | Status |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| KS4815874   | DELL Server   | S47811  | Store Main Unit | Spare  |

Select Product_Name inner join Product_Customer.Product_Id = Product.Product_Id then inner join Product.Product_Id_T = Product_Total.Product_Id_T
```

but how I can write it in sql command

and if i want to select some data from all the table using select join [or other option],how can i do it??

```
Select Project_Name,Project_Detail,PR_Id,PO,PO_Date,Delivery_Id,Delivery_Date,Brand_Name,Product_Name,EQ,Price_PerUnit,etc... (very long)
```

Answer (score 0):

the inner join is produce a new virtual table with the rows according to the ON condition

so you can do as much as you want from inner join

```
select ...... 

from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id // produce a new table 
            inner join table3 on table2.id = table3.id
            and so on .....
```

so after the first inner join :

```
table1     * table2                           table3 
**********************    inner join with    ********
column...  * column...                        column...
```

after the second inner join:

```
table1      *      table2      *    table3
*******************************************
column...   *   column...      *    column...
```